# Can you dive right into CasperJS/PhantomJS with minimal knowledge of Javascript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, automation, phantomjs, casperjs

As the title says, do I need a good amount of knowledge in JS before jumping into these two testing utilities? I have a fairly good grasp of HTML/CSS and I've done a good amount of work in ActionScript (various microsites, kiosks, etc.)

I'm trying to pickup a useful tool for automation testing, I've tried/done Selenium, I've written some basic Python scripts, though, I just need something for very quick testing. I am not interested in cross-browser compatibility, just something I can run on my machine for basic tests.

Examples of some tests:

- Check for images, to see if they exist on the page
- Click navigation, i.e., get from point A to point B
- Capture screenshots
- Fill forms

I'm not an expert in automation, so any and all help/advice/suggestions is very much appreciated.

Comment: ActionScript and JavaScript are almost the same language, so it should not take you too much time to pick it up. But since PhantomJS is just a displayless run environment for JavaScript code, you can't do anything at all with PhantomJS unless you do some JavaScript (or have someone do it for you).

Comment: I did notice some similarities already while viewing some code samples, and I'm sure I will more the deeper I dive into this, similarly, I know I will run into many new things as well. Thank you for you input.

Answer (score 0):

You'll definetly need more JS knowledge if you want to use PhantomJS on its own and it would be a pain even if you would be an expert. I suggest you to use CasperJS. The docs are good, so that you can copy and paste most of the stuff and change some little detail.

This little detail will be most of the time a CSS selector or an XPath selector. Since you have experience with CSS, you won't have a problem with the former.

You will have to understand how CasperJS works. There are mainly two things:

1. all `wait*` and `then*` functions are asynchronous, so don't mix synchronous code with asynchronous code inside of a function.
2. `evaluate` is sandboxed, but I don't think you will need it for the things you want to do.

It is still good to learn JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This is useful for me.